# ajax form post not loading in div

Tags: javascript, ajax

Sorry for the basic question for some reason, when the button is pressed then nothing happens,
I appreciate any help.

**AJAX**

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
//Form action
$("#wbForm").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: '/pages/games/game-2-ajax.php', 
        data:$('#wbForm').serialize(), 
        success: function(response) {
            $('#contenthere').find('.result').html(response);
        }});
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contenthere"></div>

<form method="POST" id="wbForm" action="/pages/games/game-2-ajax.php">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="count" style="height:25px; width:100px;" name="wager" value="" min="00.25" max="25" step="00.25" numberFormat="1.00">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-quantity=".5" value="/&#x00A;2">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-quantity="2" class="mnozstvi_sleva" value="x&#x00A;2">
<input type="submit" id="bet" class="btn btn-light" value="Bet"/>
</form>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `.result` in your HTML to write the response into.

Comment: ahhh i see so i change `.result` to the class of the div i want to output to?

Comment: Sure, as long as it's within `#contenthere`. Or just try with `$('#contenthere').html(response);`

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add a jquery library no need to write action on form open time we are using ajax submit right so no need action in form open,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```